# why system("cls") doesnt work on Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse

I've been trying to  clear the eclipse console with: `system("clr")`, `system("clear")`, `clrscr()`

I also tried `printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");`

and the thing is **i want to know why these doesnt work** on the eclipse integrated console because if i go to the executable file with the windows file explorer and run it, system("clr") works perfectly

for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int numero;

int i;
i = 0;
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
while(i != 5)
{
    printf("Ingrese un numero");
    i++;
}
system("clr");

scanf("%d", &numero);
printf("Su numero es %d", numero);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

this code in the Ecplise console doesnt clear the console after the for, but, if you run the .exe file from the windows file explorer it does, all of this was tested in windows 10 if it helps

Comment: Add error checking and do basic debugging. Check the return value of `system` to verify whether it succeeds or not. Call `perror` on failure.

Comment: It's possible the Eclipse console does not support ANSI, in which case you cannot clear it. The console just doesn't have the capability.

Comment: @tadman: At least not the normal Eclipse console. There's an ANSI console available in Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: @tadman if you refer to the ANSI escape console in the eclipse marketplace it doesnt work

Comment: Nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Eclipse does not provide any way for a program to clear the console.